# How to use MobX with react-native-navigation by Wix?

Tags: mobx, react-native-navigation, mobx-react, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

Quote from site:

> We fully support Redux, MobX and other state management libraries.

But if I try to pass store and Provider to registerComponent() I still receive error, that react-mobx can't inject store that doesn't exists. Also I've tried [Provider](https://gist.github.com/megahertz/3aad3adafa0f7d212b81f5e371863637) by megahertz, but it seems like this code is outdated.

Are there any ways to use react native navigation v2 with mobx?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a HOC in where you provide the store with a provider it works.

```
const addStore = (Component, ...props) => {
  return class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
     return (
      <Provider venues={Stores}>
        <Component {...{
          ...this.props,
          ...props,
        }} />
      </Provider>
    );
   }
  }
};

export async function RegisterScreens() {
  Navigation.registerComponent('venuesOverview', () => addStore(VenuesOverview));
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to use this solution in a case when first there's a single root, for example a login screen, and then afterwards a bottom tab layout is set using setRoot?

In this case the goal would be to have the store available both for the login and and the tabs.